# C# WPF Binding Converter not firing if bound property is null

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, binding, ivalueconverter

I'm currently facing the strange issue using WPF MVVM data binding.

The idea is to use ValueConverter that displays bound value if its not null, otherwise displays string defined in `ConverterParameter`.

`Person` class with the following properties: `Name (string)`, `Surname (string)`, `Country (class)`.

`Country` class has the following properties: `CountryName (string)`.

The use of a `IValueConverter` **fails** when TextBlock is bound to a `Person.Country.CountryName` if the `Person.Country` is null. The `IValueConverter` method `Convert` **even not firing** to check if the bound value is null or not.

At the same time `IMultiValueConverter` works just fine, firing every time whether `Person.Country` null or not null.

Ideas why it is so? Tried to search for any Microsoft articles, but found nothing.

Any help is appreciated.

Source GitHub project may be found here: https://github.com/kevintw86/WpfBindingConverterIssue.git

**Binding to IValueConverter (not working properly when Person.Country==null):**

```
<TextBlock 
          Text="{Binding Person.Country.CountryName, 
          UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
          Converter={StaticResource PersonConverter}, 
          ConverterParameter=- Not set -}"
          FontSize="16"/>
```

**PersonConverter:**

```
public class PersonConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value == null)
                return parameter;

            if (value == DependencyProperty.UnsetValue)
                return parameter;

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value.ToString()))
                return parameter;

            return value;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

**Binding to IMultiValueConverter (works fine even if Person.Country==null):**

```
<TextBlock FontSize="16">
                <TextBlock.Text>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource PersonMultiConverter}"
                                  ConverterParameter="- Not set -">
                            <MultiBinding.Bindings>
                                <Binding Path="Person.Country.CountryName"
                                     UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
                            </MultiBinding.Bindings>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </TextBlock.Text>
                </TextBlock>
```

**PersonMultiConverter:**

```
public class PersonMultiConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (values == null)
                return parameter;

            if (values[0] == DependencyProperty.UnsetValue)
                return parameter;

            if (values[0] == null)
                return parameter;

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(values[0].ToString()))
                return parameter;

            return values[0];
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

**Person class:**

```
public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _Name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _Name; }
        set 
        { 
            _Name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private string _Surname;
    public string Surname
    {
        get { return _Surname; }
        set 
        { 
            _Surname = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private Country _Country;
    public Country Country
    {
        get { return _Country; }
        set 
        {
            _Country = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged implementation

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string prop = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }

    #endregion
}
```

**Country class:**

```
public class Country : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _CountryName;
    public string CountryName
    {
        get { return _CountryName; }
        set 
        { 
            _CountryName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged implementation

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string prop = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }

    #endregion
}
```

**MainWindowViewModel:**

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        this.Person = new Person
        {
            Name = "John",
            Surname = null,
            Country = null,
        };
    }

    #region Properties

    private Person _Person;
    public Person Person
    {
        get { return _Person; }
        set 
        { 
            _Person = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged implementation

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string prop = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming `Country` is a separate class because you want to add stuff to it later?

Comment: @RolandDeschain yes, `Country` is a separate class and is a property of `Person` class.

Comment: Anyways, your converter is working fine: If you add `Person.Country = new Country() { CountryName = null};` to the ctr of `MainViewModel`, your CountryName is still `null` but it shows what you expect. Seems to me the reason is, that without the line, the `PropertyChanged` event is never fired for `CountryName`. No idea though, why it works with Multibinding...

Comment: As a note, setting `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` here is pointless. It only affects TwoWay or OneWayToSource Bindings, and has no relation with the PropertyChanged event.

Comment: You could off course handle missing bindings or null values with [FallbackValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.data.binding.fallbackvalue?view=winrt-22000) and [TargetNullValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.data.binding.targetnullvalue?view=winrt-22000#windows-ui-xaml-data-binding-targetnullvalue), and really only use the converte for empty strings.

Comment: For "*Ideas why it is so?*" - if a Binding in a MultiBinding fails (e.g. because the ContryName property of a non-existing object can not be evaluated), any other Bindings may still produce a value. The converter gets an UnsetValue for the failed Binding then. On the other hand it makes obviously no sense to call the converter of a failed regular Binding. It is not like in your question title that the "*bound property is null*", but instead that the bound property can not be evaluated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

consider using [TargetNullValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.bindingbase.targetnullvalue?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) and [FallbackValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.bindingbase.fallbackvalue?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) instead of converter:

```
<TextBlock 
      Text="{Binding Person.Country.CountryName, 
      TargetNullValue='- Not set -', 
      FallbackValue='- Not set -'}"
```